# How to create a daily timeseries

Tags: r, time-series

I'm trying to build a daily time serie with the following dataset structure:

```
> head(eg, n = 1)
# A tibble: 1 × 3
  date        var1  var2
  <date>     <dbl> <dbl>
1 2022-12-21   453 5324.
> tail(eg, n = 1)
# A tibble: 1 × 3
  date        var1  var2
  <date>     <dbl> <dbl>
1 2023-06-14   619 6311.
> glimpse(eg)
Rows: 176
Columns: 3
$ date <date> 2022-12-21, 2022-12-22, 2022-12-23, 2022-12-24, 2022-12-25, 202…
$ var1 <dbl> 453, 277, 359, 321, 251, 259, 258, 248, 317, 334, 326, 437, 449,…
$ var2 <dbl> 5324.073, 3107.398, 3716.288, 3315.080, 3541.247, 3810.109, 3905…
```

See that it does have 176 values, and when I run ts() in it, it returns me a serie with 178 values, besides the scale of time is insane, it should begin ate 21st december of 2022 and ending at 14th june of 2023.

```
> prd <- eg[3]
> prd <- ts(prd, start = c(2022,1), end = c(2023,176), frequency = 2)
> prd
Time Series:
Start = c(2022, 1) 
End = c(2110, 2) 
Frequency = 2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

ts class is not a great fit for a daily series with annual cycle. ts is mostly used for monthly, quarterly and annual series.  If you want to shoehorn it into a ts object then remove one day from every leap year (here we remove the last day, Dec 31, of leap years) so that each year has 365 days. Also the ith day of year y (where i=0, 1, ..., 364) is represented by the number y+i/365 and frequency is 365.

If `eg` is your data frame then

```
tt <- with(as.POSIXlt(eg$date),
  ts(eg[yday < 365, -1], start = year[1] + 1900 + yday[1]/365, frequency = 365)
)
```

This can be used to convert the numeric times to dates

```
as.Date(paste0(as.integer(time(tt)), "-01-01")) + as.integer(cycle(tt)) - 1
```

Alternately represent this as a zoo or xts series directly.

```
library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo(eg)

range(time(z))

library(xts)
x <- as.xts(z)
```